# Setting the cursor to the middle in TASM

Tags: assembly, x86, dos, tasm

So currently I our professor tasked us to do a program wherein it takes the time and date of the computer and displays it in the center of the screen inside a box which is also in the center...

Here is my code so far...

```
.MODEL SMALL
.Stack 200h
.DATA


Monday DB 13,10,'Today is Monday!',13,10,'$'
Tuesday DB 13,10,'Today is Tuesday!',13,10,'$' 
Wednesday DB 13,10,'Today is Wednesday!',13,10,'$'
Thursday DB 13,10,'Today is Thursday!',13,10,'$'
Friday DB 13,10,'Today is Friday!',13,10,'$' 
Saturday DB 13,10,'Today is Saturday!',13,10,'$'
Sunday DB 13,10,'Today is Sunday!',13,10,'$'



.CODE
 mov ax,@data
 mov ds,ax
```

The program clears the screen to make way for the box and date and time.

```
;Clear Screen
 mov ah,06h
 mov al,00h
 mov bh,00h
 mov cx,0000h
 mov dx,184fh                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
 int 10h
```

The program creates a window

```
;Create window
 mov ax,0605h
 mov bh,04h
 mov cx,0a08h
 mov dx, 0e34h
 int 10h
```

Can't get the cursor to be set to the middle

```
;get cursor
 mov ah,3
 mov bh,0
 int 10h

;Set cursor
 mov ax,2
 mov bh,0
 mov dl,39
 int 10h                               

Get_system_date:
 mov ah,2ah
 int 21h
 cmp al,00
 je Sun
 cmp al,01
 je Mon
 cmp al,03
 je Wedn
 cmp al,05
 je Fridy                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
 jne exit






Fridy:
 mov ah,09h
 mov dx, OFFSET friday
 int 21h
 jmp exit

exit:
mov ah,4ch
int 21h
END
```

Comment: when you set the cursor you aren't setting _DH_ which is the row. Were you trying to set the row based on the get cursor call just before it?

Comment: well i guess... i don't know just learned this topic today don't know how to properly execute the codes needed